# 'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found' when importing sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip, python-wheel

Python version: 3.5.2

I installed sklearn and some other packages form pip. All of them were installed successfully except sklearn so, I downloaded the wheel and installed it from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). It was successfully installed but when i tried to import it in order to check correct installation, I got tons of errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\MyFiles\Programs\Python\PlayGround.py", line 1, in 
> import sklearn
> File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn_*init*_.py", line 134, in 
> from .base import clone
> File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in 
> from .utils.fixes import signature
> File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_*init*_.py", line 11, in 
> from .validation import (as_float_array,
> File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in 
> from ..utils.fixes import signature
> File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 144, in 
> from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
> File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg_*init*_.py", line 114, in 
> from .isolve import *
> File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
> from .iterative import *
> File "C:\Users\Vaibhav Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in 
> from . import _iterative
> **ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

And the code was just:

```
import sklearn
```

I have already checked correct version of wheel package which I have downloaded.

How can I correct it and why it is occurring?

Comment: I suggest to uninstall sklearn and other dependencies and reinstalling them. It will be better if you can use Conda environment if its available.

Comment: Are you sure that the `pip` version you have used is the same as the Python environment you are working with?

Comment: I didn't understand? Please explain. @none

Comment: @SreeramTP Tried, Not worked!

Comment: In my console, if I type `pip<tab>` Bash autocompletes with the following: `None@vacuum:~$ pip
pip     pip3    pip3.5  pip3.6`. That means I have several versions of `pip` installed. `pip3.5` will work with Python `3.5.x` only and `pip3.6` only with Python `3.6.x`. You need to use the appropriate `pip` version.

Comment: Have you tried installing both `numpy` and `scipy` from Gohlke's website, to have the same compiler than `sklearn`?

Comment: I am having only python 3.5 installed so no other versions of pip. @none

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps solved my problem :

1. Uninstalling numpy, sklearn and scipy.
2. Downloading numpy+mkl and scipy from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).
3. Firstly installing numpy+mkl and then scipy.
4. Installing sklearn from pip.

Answer (score 1):

Various things need to be checked:

1. Check numpy, scipy installation versions.
2. If they are correct then try to import numpy and scipy.
3. If they getting imported correctly, then clear your `temp(c:/users/username/Appdata/local/temp)`folder. Restart the machine and try again.
4. Still if doesn't work, then uninstall scipy, numpy , sklearn and
   reinstall the proper wheel files

Answer (score 0):

Download and install numpy+mkl file.

Currently you might have installed only the numpy file.

1. Go to: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
2. Download the corresponding wheel file in which is suitable for your python installation
3. `pip install "/path_to_thefile/numpy-1.14.6+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"`

This should help you